# How should a unique ptr class pass its instance pointer to its member objects

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

How should a unique ptr class pass its instance pointer to its member objects.
I came up with the following way and wanted to know if there was a better way.
In the following example the object f is passing its instance ptr to its member object as a raw pointer. I wanted to know if this is ok or is there a better and safer way of doing this ?

```
class bar;

struct foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<bar> bar_ptr;    
};

struct bar
{
   const foo* raw_foo_ptr;
   bar()  {   }
   void setfoo(const foo* p)
   {raw_foo_ptr = p;}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> f(new foo());
    f->bar_ptr.reset(new bar());
    f->bar_ptr->setfoo(f.get());
}
```

Comment: what precisely is the question? is it "how do I pass a non owning pointer to another object?". what would better mean for you? safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in cases like this where `foo` has clear ownership of `bar` and will clearly outlive `bar` then a non-owning raw-pointer pointing back to `foo` like this is fine.

Although, I might write it slightly differently.  If possible I would set the back pointer at construction time and I would use `std::make_unique` if it is available.

```
class bar;

struct foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<bar> bar_ptr;    
};

struct bar
{
   const foo* raw_foo_ptr;
   bar(const foo* p) : raw_foo_ptr(p) { }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = std::make_unique<foo>();
    f->bar_ptr = std::make_unique<bar>(f.get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your pointer is not really unique (you want your object to be managed by multiple pointers), you should use `std::shared_ptr` instead. In this case, bar instance should have `weak_ptr` to it's "parent" in order to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Well other objects do not own it . Thats why its a constant raw pointer. I dont know if that is okay ? If i were to make it a shared pointer then then bar would have it as a weak pointer am i correct ?

Comment: This is a classic example of where a `shared_ptr` is a really bad idea. If `foo` owns `bar` and `bar` owns `foo` then you effectively have a memory leak. One way around it is to use a `weak_ptr` instead. In this case though I think raw pointer is fine.